# Using braces in if statements increases memory usage?

Tags: php, if-statement

This is basic programming question. I'm a PHP developer, but this is open for everyone also.

If i use

```
if(something == something){ // do something }
```

Would that be slower to run than

```
if(something == something) // do something
```

because when you have braces the compiler checks if there might be another if statement or a loop inside it?

Comment: Why do you care? The difference during execution will not be noticeable.

Comment: trust me when I say this: It does not matter, since your code might be full of such obvious bottlenecks like db calls, foreach loops, recursions etc.

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil,use braces maintain readibility

Comment: I would suggest you always use braces since it will make your code more readable and less pervious to bugs

Comment: The compiler has to check for another `if`-statement or actually any other statement in both cases. Consider this: `if (1==1) if (2==2) foreach($x as $key => $value) print "done";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 if(1==1)
   if(2==3)
      echo 'yes 2 equals 2';
   else
      echo'2 not equals 3';
 else
  echo '1 not equals 1';
?>
```

O/P : '2 not equals 3'
Look at the above example and its output even if you dnt use braces compiler still have to check if there is another if statement.

Comment: I'm wrong then. :) It was a wrong thought.

Answer (score 2):

Irrelevant. Premature micro-optimization. Start worrying about such things when you notice your application actually being slow. Then do benchmarks or profiling.

Write the code that is clearest to read to yourself and other programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You said "slower" but you weren't very specific. Slower to compile or slower to run.

It's insignificantly slower to compile and probably insignificantly slower to run (if the code is not compiled to bytecode, in which case they would be equally fast).